# Micromax A110Q - SD Card space becomes 0 bytes in few hours

Tags: storage, android-versions

I have formatted my SD Card many many times and when I format it - I get the full space of 7.5 GB and after few hours of using the phone - getting images from whatsapp and other content - It becomes full and space comes to ZERO BYTES even though the images are just a few MBs.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Try plugging the card into a computer to see what is really on there taking up all the space?

Comment: Hard to answer without more details. Please follow the advice of *Anti Veeranna*, and then [edit] your post with additional information.